# Using Mono Spaced Fonts on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

[image: Mono Spaced Font]

I am trying to write an application that shows guitar tabs among other things. However, right now I am running into the issue where Mono Spaced font's are not being displayed correctly. As the image above shows numbers such as 0 and 2 have more width than some others. The font used below is an example done with Consolas, but this occurs with all monospaced fonts I try on Windows Phone including Segoe UI Mono and others.

Has anyone else encountered this error and/or found a way to solve it?

A Note: Interestingly, the layout below appears correctly in the UI designer for Visual Studio. The issue only exists on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was occurring because I was not Embedding the font in my application. Doing so resolved the issue. Turns out Windows Phone's built in font selection is smaller than I expected.